# Do regard a crossed horizontal asymptote while finding range , or not since it was crossed

Tags: calculus

If a horizontal asymptote is crossed after reciprocating an exponential function , should I include the horizontal asymptote when trying to find the range of my new function .

Answer (score 0):

Your wording a a little confusing. A picture would help. But I think I can guess what you mean.

The answer to your question is probably "yes". If there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = h$ then $h$ is in the range of $f$ whether or not somewhere else it's the height of a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Well thanks , then can you explain why didn't wolfram alpha include the crossed horizontal asymptote for this function f(x)= | abs((x - 1)/(x + 1))

Comment: The WA graph is right. It shows the pole at $-1$, the value $1$ at $0$, the root at $1$ and the horizontal asymptote (not drawn) at height $1$ as $x$ grows. That horizontal line is only relevant for large $x$.

Comment: I mean when I ask WA for the range it doesn't regard the existence of the horizontal asymptote

Comment: Why should it? The horizontal asymptote has nothing to do with the range, which in this case is the set of all positive real numbers. That's the whole point of my answer.